# mongoose doesn't update model by ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
apiRoutes.put('/intake/:id', function(req, res)  {
  var id = req.params.id;
  Intake.findById({id, function(err, intake) {
      if (err)res.send(err);

        intake.check = true;
        intake.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Error'});}
      res.json({success: true, msg: 'Successful update check state.'});
    });
  }})
});
```

What's problem? In console i see ID, it's ok, but database have no change

Comment: Is `check` a valid property in your schema? Also, you want want to consider using [`findByIdAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) so you can perform the find and the update with one command.

Comment: i add the field  required: true in schema but still doesn't work

Comment: Can you add your schema to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intake.findById(/*remove { here*/id, function(err, intake) {
      if (err)res.send(err);

        intake.check = true;
        intake.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Error'});}
      res.json({success: true, msg: 'Successful update check state.'});
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You gave us too few information to help you. But I got some hints on how to find out what's going wrong: (I added example code a the end of my answer.)

Use a proper formatting of your code. Mistakes are easier to find.

Please avoid `res.send(err)`. Most express apps provide an error to HTML Page translation at the end of the route pipe. This only works if you call `res.next(err);`. If your app does not provide error page generating at the end of the pipe then, you could use `res.status(400).json({success: false, msg: err.message});`.

After the use of `res.send` or `res.next` or `res.json` you have to end the execution of the function by `return` before one of these functions can be called a second time. This can be very complicated in case of nested or asynchrounous method calls. But in your example it's quite easy.

Use some log outputs to see which part of the code you reach and which not.

`console.dir(<object>);` prints out the structure of this object.

Hope this helps a little bit. ;-)

```
apiRoutes.put('/intake/:id', function(req, res)  
{
  var id = req.params.id;
  Intake.findById(id, function(err, intake) 
  {
    if (err)
    {
      res.next(err);
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }

    console.log("Modify check attribute");
    intake.check = true;
    console.dir(intake);
    intake.save(function(err) 
    {
      console.log("Intake save called!");

      if (err) 
      {
        console.error(err);
        res.json({
          success: false, 
          msg: 'Error'
        });
        return;
      }

      console.log("Success");
      res.json({
        success: true, 
        msg: 'Successful update check state.'
      });
    });
  }})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
Intake.update({_id: req.params.id},
                {
                   check : true
                },

                function(err){
                    if(err){
                     console.log(err);
                     res.status(400).send(err.errors);
                }else{
                    res.status(200).end();
                }
        });
```